# How do you proxy a specific image with Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I have this url

https://example.com/image/test.jpg

And i would like to proxy with Nginx the image at this url

https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2018/02/google-pacman-796x419.jpg

without the url changing i.e. staying the same as this https://example.com/image/test.jpg

What would you put in the location block to get this to happen?

Comment: Can you share your nginx config please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `proxy_pass` parameter in your nginx config:

```
server {
    # ...
    server_name example.com;
    # ...

    location /image/test.jpg {
        proxy_pass https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2018/02/google-pacman-796x419.jpg;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i do that it redirect me to  this url https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2018/02/google-pacman-796x419.jpg; rather than keeping me on example.com/image/test.jpg